# How to verify a users password?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, security

Basically I'm developing a website in ASP.NET MVC 4 and I see that there's a built in function to verify the current (old) password during a password change:

```
WebSecurity.ChangePassword(User.Identity.Name, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
```

However what if I wanted to verify the password when changing the email of the user? The built in function only supports changing the password? How can I verify that the user knows the current password before changing the email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following method from the Membership class:

```
Membership.ValidateUser(string username, string password)
```

The documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx).